# How to use inline JavaScript inside HTML files?

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to use JavaScript tags inside HTML files in Electron.

I know I can use code like this in main.js:

`webPreferences: {       preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),     },`

And then import this script in HTML files like this:

`<script>alert("This works!")</script>`

But why can't I just use JavaScript like this inside HTML files:

```
alert("Why won't this work?");
```

There is a default meta tag in HTML when I follow Electron's quick start guide:
`<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'" />`

And this I guess disables executing inline JavaScript.

So my question is, is it bad practice to use inline JavaScript like this in Electron? Should this be avoided?

Comment: _"But why can't I just use JavaScript like this inside HTML files:"_ Do you mean without using `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: _"And this I guess disables executing inline JavaScript."_ That's not correct. Your meta tag only disallows **external** script sources. If you are not able to use `<script>` tags, then there is probably a script that is parsing your code.

Comment: @RezaSaadati I thought that `'unsafe-inline'` was required in the CSP to allow `<script></script>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources#sources

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use javascript inside HTML files by using the script tag .

```
<script>
     //code goes here
</script>
```

now coming to use of inline javascript its not a good practice if you are creating a project because then it will be hard to maintain if you start working with multiple files.

Comment: Should this inline JavaScript be avoided in Electron?

Comment: Best practice is to use separate files for your JavaScript but, as with most things, the decision is up to you.

Comment: Exactly as @phuzi mentioned its better to have separate JS files but if you are say using only one HTML file and want to add just a little bit of javascript its fine to use the script tag